# randomForest error shown NA not permitted in predictors

Tags: r

Can I get some help and suggestion from you guys since I am trying to run randomForest in classification problem on currency data but I got this pop-up showing NA not permitted in predictors. However, I have tried to solve it by myself but still cannot figure it out.

```
library(priceR)
library(tidyverse)  
library(quantmod) 
library(dplyr)
```

Get the data

```
a <- historical_exchange_rates("THB", to = "USD",start_date = "2010-01-01", end_date = "2021-12-31")
```

Set up input indicators

```
a.avg10 <- rollapply(a[,2],10,mean)   
a.avg20 <- rollapply(a[,2],20,mean)   
a.std10 <- rollapply(a[,2],20,sd)   
a.std20 <- rollapply(a[,2],20,sd) 
a.rsi5 <- na.omit(RSI(a[,2],5,"SMA"))   
a.rsi14 <- na.omit(RSI(a[,2],14,"SMA"))  
a.macd12269 <- na.omit(MACD(a[,2],12,26,9,"SMA"))   
a.macd7205 <- na.omit(MACD(a[,2],7,20,5,"SMA"))   
a.bbands <- na.omit(BBands(a[,2],20,"SMA",2))
```

Create variable direction

```
a.direction <- a %>% mutate(direction = ifelse(one_THB_equivalent_to_x_USD - lag(one_THB_equivalent_to_x_USD, 10) <= 0, 0, 1))
```

Combining variables

```
a.data <- cbind(a[1:4350,2],a.avg10[1:4350],a.avg20[1:4350],a.bbands[1:4350,1:4],a.std10[1:4350],a.std20[1:4350],a.rsi5[1:4350],a.rsi14[1:4350],a.macd12269[1:4350,1:2],a.macd7205[1:4350,1:2],a.direction[1:4350,3])
```

Train and test

```
a.split <- sample(c(rep(0,0.7*nrow(a.data)),rep(1,0.3*nrow(a.data))))
```

Building in-sample and out-sample datasets

```
isa.data <- a.data[a.split == 0,]  
osa.data <- a.data[a.split == 1,]
```

Standardizing the dataset of in-sample and out-sample

```
ismea.data <- sapply(isa.data,mean,2) 
issta.data <- apply(isa.data,2,sd)   
isida.data <- matrix (1,dim(isa.data)[1],dim(isa.data)[2])  

osmea.data <- sapply(osa.data,mean,2)  
ossta.data <- apply(osa.data,2,sd)  
osida.data <- matrix (1,dim(osa.data)[1],dim(osa.data)[2])
```

Normalizing the data

```
norma.data <- (isa.data - t(ismea.data*t(isida.data)))/t(issta.data*t(isida.data))  
normosa.data <- (osa.data - t(osmea.data*t(osida.data)))/t(ossta.data*t(osida.data))
```

Replacing last column with variable direction

```
a.dm <- dim(isa.data)
norma.data[,a.dm[2]] <- a.direction[1:3045,3]   
normosa.data[,a.dm[2]] <- a.direction[3046:4350,3]
```

Combine as dataframe

```
isnorma.data <- as.data.frame(norma.data)   
osnorma.data <- as.data.frame(normosa.data)   
colnames(isnorma.data) <- c("exchage rate", "avg10", "avg20", "down", "mavg", "up", "pctB", "std10", "std20", "rsi5", "rsi14", "macd12269", "signal12269", "macd7205", "signal7205", "Direction")   
colnames(osnorma.data) <- c("exchage rate", "avg10", "avg20", "down", "mavg", "up", "pctB", "std10", "std20", "rsi5", "rsi14", "macd12269", "signal12269", "macd7205", "signal7205", "Direction")
```

Modelling with random forest

```
rfisnorma.data <- isnorma.data %>% select(-Direction)   
rfosnorma.data <- osnorma.data %>% select(-Direction)
```

Labeling train and test data with direction

```
a.lagret <- (a[,2] - lag(a[,2],10))/ lag(a[,2],10)   
rfa.direction <- NULL   
rfa.direction[a.lagret > 0.02] <- "Up"   
rfa.direction[a.lagret < -0.02] <- "Down"  
rfa.direction[a.lagret < 0.02 & a.lagret > -0.02] <- "Nowhere"   
isdira.data <- rfa.direction[1:3045]  
osdira.data <-  rfa.direction[3046:4350]
```

Convert labeled data into factors as only accepted by randomForest

```
isdira.data <- na.omit(as.factor(isdira.data))   
osdira.data <- na.omit(as.factor(osdira.data))
```

Modelling data with input parameters

```
rfmodela.data <- randomForest(rfisnorma.data[11:3045,1:15], y=as.factor(isdira.data), xtest=rfosnorma.data, ytest=as.factor(osdira.data), ntree=500, importance=TRUE)
```

In this step is where I got an error "NA not permitted in predictors"

Comment: norma.data[,a.dm[2]] norma.data and a.dm is not defined in the place it should be, so there are missing data here

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I forgot to write that down in my post but in my codes, it does have "a.dm" in there.  So, is it possible for you to try running the codes again?

Answer (score 0):

You have missing data somewhere between 2840 and 2850 if you replace the last line of code with the lines I show bellow it should run. You can use the arguments  xtest=xtest[index,], ytest=y[index] but I am not sure if you want them since the test data are the same with the train data. Please check the documentation to make sure that you are doing the right thing.

```
tempdata<-xtest<-rfisnorma.data[11:3045,1:15]
y<-as.factor(as.character(isdira.data))
index<-c(1:2840,2850:nrow(tempdata))
rfmodela.data <- randomForest(tempdata[index,], y=y[index], ntree=500, importance=TRUE)
summary(rfmodela.data)
```